# Javascript : get content from clipboard with formatting

Tags: clipboard

I have a requirement to customise(filter) copied content(from any source) before pasting into my content editable div.

I am using javasctipt window.clipboardData.getData("Text") to get copied content from clipboard. However this method returns only the plain text. I want to get the copied content as is without loosing its formatting. How can I do it?  window.clipboardData.getData("Html") doesn't seems to be working. I am using Internet Explorer 11.

Answer (score -1):

you can try with this

```
var $temp = $("<input>");
$("body").append($temp);
$temp.val($( this ).attr('name')).select();
document.execCommand("copy");
$temp.remove();
```

and paste

Comment: I don't want to copy using javascript. My requirement is to get copied content from clipboard without loosing formatting. I can copy content from external source as well (e.g. from ms word)